# apexchart use custom color for negative values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apexcharts

I use apex charts in react, and I want to show the different marker color if y value is negative number

I use this logic to get the values

```
        const colorMarkers = data
          .map((point, index) =>
            (Array.isArray(point.data) ? point.data : [point.data]).map(
              (dataValue, dataPointIndex) => {
                const isNegative = dataValue < 0;
                return {
                  dataPointIndex: dataPointIndex,
                  fillColor: isNegative ? "#DF2829" : "#56C5D0",

                };
              }
            )
          )
          .flat();
```

And the output is
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw9XX.jpg)

I try to use it as color with this code:

```
             markers: {
                size: 5,
                colors: discreteMarkers.map(marker => marker.fillColor),

            },
```

But not change the color.
Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For Multi Line Chart - My Solution for Markers Colors

```
    const series = [
      {
        name: 'Goals',
        data: [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
      },
      {
        name: 'Leads',
        data: [46, 12, 55, 123, 10, 77, 99, 5, 66, 5, 77, 10, 177, 99, 188]
      }
    ]
    
    const options = {
    chart: {
      parentHeightOffset: 0,
      zoom: { enabled: false },
      toolbar: { show: false }
    },
    colors: ['#a2b3e0', '#78f593'],
    stroke: {
      dashArray: [5, 0],
      curve: 'straight',
      width: 2
    },
    legend: {
      offsetY: -5,
      offsetX: -30,
      position: 'top',
      fontSize: '13px',
      horizontalAlign: 'right',
      labels: { colors: 'grey' },
      itemMargin: {
        vertical: 4,
        horizontal: 10
      },
      markers: {
        width: 12,
        height: 12,
        radius: 10,
        offsetY: 1,
        // offsetX: theme.direction === 'ltr' ? -4 : 5
      }
    },
    dataLabels: { enabled: false },
    markers: {
      size: [1, 7],
      colors: ['green'],
      discrete: series[1].data.map((item, index) => {
        return {
          size: 5,
          seriesIndex: 1,
          strokeColor: 'red',
          fillColor: 'red',
          dataPointIndex: series[1].data[index] < 50 ? index : null
        }
      })
    },
    grid: {
      padding: { top: -10 },
      borderColor: 'grey',
      xaxis: {
        lines: { show: true }
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        style: { colors: 'grey' }
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      axisBorder: { show: false },
      axisTicks: { color: 'grey' },
      crosshairs: {
        stroke: { color: 'grey' }
      },
      labels: {
        style: { colors: 'grey' }
      },
      categories: [
        '7/12',
        '8/12',
        '9/12',
        '10/12',
        '11/12',
        '12/12',
        '13/12',
        '14/12',
        '15/12',
        '16/12',
        '17/12',
        '18/12',
        '19/12',
        '20/12',
        '21/12'
      ]
    }
  }



<ReactApexcharts type='line' height={400} options={options} series={series} />
```